# Access global variable inside Jinja2 include

Tags: templates, jinja2

I have a template like so:

```
{% extends 'master.html' %}
{% set myVar = true %}

...

{% block myBlock %}
    {% include '/includes/myinclude.html' %}
{% endblock %}
```

I am unable to access `myVar` inside of my include. However, if I do this:

```
{% block myBlock %}
    {% set myVar = myVar %}
    {% include '/includes/myinclude.html' %}
{% endblock %}
```

magically, it's accessible. Obviously I don't want to have to set my variables in two different places. What am I doing wrong, or is this just a dumb thing that Jinja2 does?

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to add scoped to the block, like:

```
{% block myBlock scoped %}
    {% include '/includes/myinclude.html' %}
{% endblock %}
```

From the doc: per default blocks may not access variables from outer scopes.